# Storing prices inclusive of tax in Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, mightybigrobot

We have a requirement to charge the same price for a product, regardless of the tax. For example a product bought in the UK would be subject to 20% VAT and the price is £100 inclusive of tax.

If the same product is bought in the US, no VAT is applicable, but the price should still be £100.

In Exp:resso Store you can do this by configuring the module to store prices inclusive of tax, and then the tax is calculated in the basket. I can't see a way to do this in CT though - is this possible or would it be a custom development?

Comment: Russ, did you work out a solution for this?